# UserDefaults not working when switching classes (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, class, segue, swift4, userdefaults

My code right now takes new entries into its array. When the user hits the home button on the simulator and returns to the original view controller it works perfectly. However when the view controller is sugued to another vc and returns to the original vc and enters a new entry all of the prior entries are deleted and saved over. Basically the problem is when the user switches classes the and returns the userDefault is overwritten by a new userdefault.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var persons:[Person] = [Person]()
    @IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        let judo = Person.init(name: txt.text! )
        self.persons.append(judo)
        label.text = String(describing: persons)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(label.text, forKey: "name")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let name = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
            label.text = name
        }

    }

    struct Person :  CustomStringConvertible  {
        var name: String
        static var myStruct = [String]();
        var description: String {
            return   "\(name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use value forkey. You should use userdefaults method `string(forKey:)`. btw name it is already a string, no need to do a string interpolation `return name`

Comment: And don't use `String(describing:)` method. Use string interpolation if needed `"\(persons)"`

Comment: And you should call `super.viewDidLoad()` when overriding viewDidLoad method

Comment: label's text property it is optional you should unwrap it before saving it to user defaults `UserDefaults.standard.set(label.text!, forKey: "name")`. Btw you shouldn't use labels to pass around values. Add an instance property to your view controller and use it to set your user defaults value.